# Converting logical addresses to physical address using a segment table

Tags: memory

If I am provided with segments from 0-4, with BASE = 515, 1250, 825, 2500, 60 respectively and LENGTH = 300, 99, 400, 319, 80 respectively, how will I convert Logical address to the Physical Address?

```
Logical Address  Physical Address
2, 175          -     ?
4, 61           -     ?
5, 75           -     ?
0, 2            -     ?
3, 920          -     ?
```

Answer (score 1):

Well i am not sure of this answer. Please tell me whether i am right. 
In 1st case : 2,175 - the page number is 2 and offset is 175. 
To convert to physical , page number is replaced by frame number
825(segment 2) , 175(offset remains same)

so finally 825,175 is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite. You need to add the base address to the offset. (825+175 = 1000). This is ok as 175<400=length. O/w answer is "trap".

Answer (score 0):

Let me explain by taking first logical address
2,175 here it means referring 175th byte of segment 2.
Now check if this 175 is less than 400(limit) from segment table(base,limit). If true then add base register value with offset 
That is.  825+175= 1000
Therefore 1000 is the address in physical address space

If false its either a trap or miss.